# How to return correct boolean in recursive function?

Tags: recursion, return, boolean, terminate, callstack

I know that the general template for recursive functions requires a return statement for each case.  Consider this recursive function, which should (but fails to) return true if a given integer list can make 24 through the arithmetic operators (`*`,`/`,`+`,`-`).

```
static boolean doArith(List<Double> A, double temp, int start) {
    // base case
    if (start == A.size()) return temp == 24;

    // recursive calls
    for (int op = 0; op < 4; op++) {
        doArith(A,
                arith(temp,op,A.get(start)),
                start+1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Through print statements in the base case block, I know for certain my code correctly identifies when 24 has been made. However, it fails to return true when the call stack resolves.

I've tried refactoring the code, even hard coding the for loop into 4 separate calls, but as expected, that didn't work.

(**Edit:** In response to @Caramiriel comment) I tried rewriting the function as:

```
static boolean doArith(List<Double> A, double temp, int start) {
    // base case
    if (start == A.size()) return temp == 24;

    boolean b = false;
    // recursive calls
    for (int op = 0; op < 4; op++) {
        b = doArith(A,
                arith(temp,op,A.get(start)),
                start+1);
    }
    return b;
}
```

But this still returns always `false`.

How do I get this function to return `true` the moment it comes across such a case?

Thanks

Comment: Youre not handling the result value from `doArith()` inside the loop.

Comment: I tried to but that didn't work. I will add this to an edit

Comment: In the for loop, check if b is true, return b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the operation that causes the result to be `24`, you know the answer is right and need to break from the loop:

```
static boolean doArith(List<Double> A, double temp, int start) {
    // base case
    if (start == A.size()) return temp == 24;

    // recursive calls
    for (int op = 0; op < 4; op++) {
        boolean b = doArith(A,
                arith(temp,op,A.get(start)),
                start+1);

        if(b) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The following code:

```
boolean b = false;
// recursive calls
for (int op = 0; op < 4; op++) {
    b = doArith(A,
            arith(temp,op,A.get(start)),
            start+1);
}
```

just checks for the last case (`op = 3`).

Comment: Great! Could you explain why only `op = 3` is checked? Don't the 3 previous calls matter? Thanks :)

Comment: Because you overwrite variable `b` for every loop iteration in the last example. The last value is the only value that retains. When `doArith` has been executed and the result is assigned to `b`, the next iteration of the loop will be executed, thus the value of `b` isn't relevant anymore as it will be overwritten anyway. The only value that remains is the last value from the loop.